# Only select bold & underline text in current paragraph (VBA macro, word 2016)

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]I'm trying to select any bolded & underlined text in a paragraph (in Microsoft word 2016). I really just want to select the text so I can manipulate in various ways (which will constantly vary depending on my needs for that specific text), eg highlight, unbold, copy etc.

I created the below macro using the macro recorder feature and when I was doing it it worked perfectly. But when I subsequently ran the macro it highlighted the whole paragraph, as opposed to just the bolded & underlined parts.

```
Sub SelectBoldandUnderlineCurrentParagraph()
'
' SelectBoldandUnderlineCurrentParagraph Macro
'
'
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find.Font
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    End With
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
With Selection.Paragraphs.First.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  .Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This does select bolded & underline text. However it only selects the first word in a paragraph that is bolded & underlined. I would like to select ALL the words/letters that are bolded and underlined. Is this possible?

Comment: That would only happen if your bolded & underlined content is in discontiguous ranges - as per your example (note, for example, the break in the underlining). Macros cannot select discontiguous ranges.

Comment: Thanks again. I know that you can select discontiguous  range with the 'Find & Replace' function in Word, by selecting 'Find in - Current Selection'. But just to confirm you can't reproduce this via a macro?

Comment: As I already said «Macros *cannot* select discontiguous ranges».